# Find size of a portion of a file in C++/C?

Tags: c++, c

I have my data in a large file on disk. Now I want to find the size (in bytes) of some part of this data  without dumping this data to a separate file. Is it possible to do so.

E.g. lets say my file is of 10000000000 lines. Now I want to find the size of 1000000 lines. I know I can store these 100 lines in a separate file and find its size but I dont want to do this. Is there some other way out or is this the only way out.

Comment: if every line of equal byte you can roughly divide by total size. Otherwise you have to read file.

Comment: You will have to read the file (unless the lines are all the same length!).

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no. You can read (but not store) the data you care about, and use `ftell`/`tellg` to find your current file position. So, get to the start of what you care about, get position, read to end of what you care about, get position again, and then subtract to get size.

The reason that's "yes and no" is that the C and C++ standards don't guarantee that the result you get will exactly match the size of the data on disk. For example, if you're on Windows, new-lines get translated between "\r\n" externally and "\n" internally -- and the standard doesn't say whether that will be counted as one or two characters.

If that's not sufficient for your purposes, you can read through your data one character at a time, and count the characters. With this you can take vagaries of the platform into account as you see fit (e.g., adding an extra character to the count for `\n` under Windows).

Comment: The simple answer is: officially no, but if you're on a Unix machine or on Windows, taking the difference between two `tellg` (or `ftell`, if the values will fit on a long) will work.

Comment: @JamesKanze And this code: `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++) while((c=getc(fp))=='\n') break; size_100 = ftell (fp);` is **not** reliable.

Comment: @JamesKanze: well, taking the difference will give you some value, but it's hard to be sure what that value means. Once you figure out what it means, there's a pretty good chance that it doesn't match what you want.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan In what sense?  (He didn't actually say what he meant by the size, so we can only guess.  I was interpreting it to mean the number of bytes between the two positions on the disk; that's what the difference between two calls to `tellg` will give you (under Unix or Windows, at least).  If he means the number of char he can read, the only way is to read, counting.  If he means how much space the data would require if it were in a separate file on the disk, I don't know of a solution.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Formally, you don't have the slightest idea what it means.  Practically, under Windows or Unix, it will mean the number of char's in the range on the disk.  Under Unix, it will also mean the number of char you can actually read.

Comment: @JerryCoffin And while I'm thinking of it: if you open the file in binary mode, Windows will behave exactly like Unix.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to find the beginning and end of the section you care about, you can then use `fstream::tellg()` (or in C use `ftell(file)`) for the starting point and subtract that from `fstream::tellg()` of the ending point. But if you don't have an easy way to find the starting and ending points, there's nothing other than reading through the file until you find the bits you care about, then count the size of the content until you find the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ftell`()/`fgetpos`() at the beginning of the interesting section, than sweep until the end of that section, call the same function again, and calculate the difference, which will be the size of the section.

Keep in mind, though, that `ftell`() may get confused when working with text files on systems where text files differ from binary files (e.g. Windows).

Comment: You can't do arithmetic on the results of `fgetpos()`.